# How to insulate more of my fluke test leads

Tags: multimeter

[image]

these are the test leads I own, I am wondering if there is a something I can purchase to shield the exposed metal more to avoid incidents. I heave the little plastic shield that comes with them but they are to wide to fit in the type of terminals I use, is there any accessories I can purchase to help me with this. I preferably don't want to buy new test leads

Comment: @Davetweed -- seems like an OK question to me.  He's really asking for a technique, not a product, and one correct answer is to use heat shrink.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: That's a valid point, but the OP is explicitly rejecting "home made" solutions, and is asking **specifically** for something to purchase.

Answer (score 2):

I just put short lengths of shrink tubing on mine, so only the pointy tip is exposed.

Comment: Good idea but I'm unsure if my teacher would be happy if I just did it myself, also, to be honest, I don't think anyone who does work would ever do something like this, I've worked with trams that cost millions and there they don't care that I am measuring on exposed relays that could the worst happen to derail a tram Edit: I mean buy just a accessory to shield them not anything against your method, came out a bit wrong

Comment: Well, "anyone who does work" includes me. You should have clarified your situation in the original question. Asking for a recommendation of a product you can buy is generally considered to be off-topic for this site.

Comment: I think i would need some certified accessory that fits I've found some that would work, but they do not fit with the test lead probably because fluke has some special design

Comment: "Certified" by whom? For what purpose? Now your question is even more unclear.

Comment: oh didn't know that would be off-topic, anyway ill do some more research and look for a solution

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear ill give the whole story basically my teacher said, I need something to cover the exposed metal and if I did not get something I would fail my exam since I would use the wrong tool. I will bring your solution up with him and ask if that would be a way to solve it.

Comment: You should be aware that I only work on low-voltage circuits where this is not a safety issue. If you are worried about electrical safety at high voltages then shrink tubing is not a good solution.